# Error al conectarme a mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

Tengo instalado xampp en windows y hoy al iniciar Apache y MySQL, veo que al intentar conectarme a la base de datos, me devuelve un error

> 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading inital communication packet', system error: 0 "internal error/check (Not system error)"

Si intento acceder desde laravel me dice lo siguiente

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Si reviso el log del archivo `my.ini` de MySQL, cada vez que intento contectarme sale lo siguiente:

> [Warning] Aborted connection 11 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'localhost' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

El xampp lo abro y uso todos los días, y hoy sin modificar nada pasa esto, el puerto es el 3306.

Leyendo en foros veo que puede ser un problema del **firewall**, pero no he encontrado más información

Uso Navicat como gestor de base de datos

Comment: Si tienes el puerto `3306` destinado a MySQL revisa que el mismo no esté siendo ocupado por otro programa y de ahí venga el error. Revisa también que tienes permisos otorgados para ese puerto en el Firewall. Eso ocurre a veces cuando instalas programas nuevos que empiezan a usar el puerto que antes estaba destinado a la base de datos. Me parece que el comando de Windows para chequear los puertos es `netstat`